# SODA API Filtering

Tags: python-3.x, socrata, soda

I am trying to filter through ny gov open database with their SODA API. I am following the docs on how to filter, but it is returning an empty dataframe.

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import numpy as np
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import pandas as pd
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from sodapy import Socrata


clientNYgov = Socrata('data.ny.gov', None)
```

Here is where I am trying to find only results in NY.

```
databaseM = clientNYgov.get('yg7h-zjbf.csv?business_city=NEW+YORK')

dfDatabaseM = pd.DataFrame.from_records(databaseM)

dfDatabaseM.to_csv('Manhattan Agents.csv')
print(dfDatabaseM)
```

But here is the Empty Output:

```
0                   1   ...              9             10
0  business_address_1  business_address_2  ...  license_number  license_type

[1 rows x 11 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please let me know if there's a problem with how I am filtering, not quite sure what is going wrong here. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Socrata uses a json endpoint to export the files via the API. This is found in the top right hand corner of the dataset when selecting API. For this solution I am using just requests to retrieve the data. The Soda module is nice to use, but works the same as a request.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

data=requests.get('http://data.ny.gov/resource/yg7h-zjbf.json?$limit=50000&business_city=NEW YORK').json()
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to do this with filters.

**Method 1**

This can be done using `Socrata()` by passing the [filters using SQL](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/xmunoz/sodapy/blob/master/examples/soql_queries.ipynb#Query-strings) to the `query` keyword in the `get()` method of the instantiated `Socrata` client. You will need an [application token](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy/blob/master/README.md#client). If you do not use a token, then your requests will be [subjected to throttling](https://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html#throttling-and-application-tokens). To avoid throttling, [sign up for a socrata account](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004055807-Signing-up-for-an-Account) and [create your app token](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/210138558-Generating-an-App-Token)

```py
query = f"""SELECT * WHERE business_city="NEW YORK" LIMIT 50000"""
client = Socrata("data.ny.gov", <YOUR-APP-TOKEN-HERE>)
results = client.get("yg7h-zjbf", query=query)
df_socrata = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

**Method 2**

Using the JSON endpoint (same as @Joseph Gattuso's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58225567/4057186))

```py
data = requests.get(
    "http://data.ny.gov/resource/yg7h-zjbf.json?"
    "$limit=50000&"
    "business_city=NEW YORK"
).json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

**Comparison of output** - Verify that the two methods return the same result

```py
assert df_socrata.equals(df)
```

Comment: Thanks ! First method worked perfectly

Comment: Unfortunately, the Python client library `sodapy` is no longer maintained - [1](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy), [2](https://pypi.org/project/sodapy/). The recommended approach now should be to query the [Socrata API](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/endpoints.html) directly (using [the other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58225567/4057186)).